# Sectioned Grid with checkboxes in android

Tags: android, listview

I am following this 
http://velosmobile.com/2013/04/03/enhanced-sectioned-grid-with-varying-columns/ 
tutorial in my example but i have checkbox for each list item. I want to check items and then send all the checked item to another activity.

The problem is when I scroll the listview, getview() of custom adaptor is called and the positions of the list items are changed. 
In simpler words the

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()
```

is called when listview is scrolled, which i don't want to get called.
Following is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int realPosition = 0;
    int viewsToDraw = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < sectionsCount; ++i)
    {
        int sectionCount = getCountInSection(i);
        totalCount += sectionCount;
        if (sectionCount > 0 && position <= rows + (sectionCount - 1) / colCount)
        {
            realPosition += (position - rows) * colCount;
            viewsToDraw = (int)(totalCount - realPosition);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sectionCount > 0)
            {
                rows += (int)((sectionCount - 1) / colCount + 1);
            }
            realPosition += sectionCount;
        }
    }
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(rowResID, parent, false);
        if (measuredRow == null && resizeMode == MODE_VARY_COUNT)
        {
            measuredRow = (ViewGroup)convertView;
            // In this mode, we need to learn how wide our row will be, so we can calculate
            // the number of columns to show.
            // This listener will notify us once the layout pass is done and we have our
            // measurements.
            measuredRow.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutObserver);
        }
    }
    int lastType = -1;
    if (realPosition > 0)
        lastType = getTypeFor(realPosition-1);
    if (getDataCount() > 0)
    {
        TextView header = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(headerID);
        int newType = getTypeFor(realPosition);
        if (newType != lastType)
        {
            header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            header.setText(getHeaderForSection(newType));

        }
        else
        {
            header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    customizeRow(position, convertView);

    ViewGroup itemHolder = (ViewGroup)convertView.findViewById(itemHolderID);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemHolder.getChildCount(); ++i)
    {
        View child = itemHolder.getChildAt(i);
        if (i < colCount && i < viewsToDraw && child != null)
        {
            bindView(child, realPosition + i);
            child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if (child != null)
        {
            child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The Code of the bindView() function is as follows

```
@Override
protected void bindView(View convertView, int position) {
    String title;
    ConfiguredItem myDevice = (ConfiguredItem) getItem(position);

    myDevices.add(myDevice);
    title = myDevice.getTitle();

    TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookItem_title);
    CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    mCheckBox.setTag(position);
    mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
    label.setText(title);

    TypedArray imgTitle = myContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.colors);
    String[] myColors = myContext.getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.colors);

    int idx = new Random().nextInt(imgTitle.length());
    String random = (myColors[idx]);

    int color = Color.parseColor(random);
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(color);

}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(),
                isChecked);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Faster solution: delete `if (convertView == null)` 
Always create new convertView. This not good practice, but help you find bug.

Comment: I am stuck with the checkboxes. I will be thankful if i get any help regarding that...

Answer (score 0):

Recycling views is tricky.  When you get reuse a view, you need to re-initialize everything.  For example, if you set the state of a checkbox during one incarnation of a view and then reuse it later, you'll need to set the checkbox state again or it will have the state from last time.

I can't tell from your code whether I'm addressing your issue - you don't show the member variables and there's a lot of code which doesn't seem to relate to initialization of the cell view, itself.  If my solution isn't sufficient, try reducing the code you present to small sections which relate to the problem.

Comment: i do save the state of the checkbox in sparsebooleanarray and reset state of checkbox everytime i scroll. but still the position of view gets changed somehow when i scroll up and down. I did debug it but there is no obvious solution in my mind. 
Well this is the minimum code that is related to problem otherwise it will become very difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mCheckBox.setTag(position);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
```

and in your method getView 
find the checkbox and do the same

mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

Comment: I tired it, but still there the position of view gets changed.